# два ListView в фрагменте как реализовать setOnItemClickLisenter

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment

Хочу реализовать внутри фрагмента прокрутку 2 ListView
все работает нормально и прокрутка и отображение только вот столкнулся с проблемой как реализовать OnItemClickListener
на двух ListView сразу)?

```
 public class ProgramTrainingFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.program_training_fragment_example;
private ListView listView;
private ListView listView2;
private View view;
private String[] newArray2;
private String[] newArray;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter2;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

public static ProgramTrainingFragment getInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    ProgramTrainingFragment fragment = new ProgramTrainingFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
    //
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_program_training);
    newArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.program);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newArray);
    //
    listView2 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_program_training2);
    newArray2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.program2);
    arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newArray2);
    //
    listView2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    //
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    //
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    switch (position) {
        case 0:

            break;

        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:

            break;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Поясните в чём проблема. Что вы хотите и что получили?

Comment: есть два разных ListView при клик на item в ListView хочу сделать переход на другую активити только если делать это через switch (position)  то получается что position первого ListView  и второго ListView  это один и тот же item

Comment: Это-то понятно. А что не получается? Активити не запускается? Или слушатель нажатия не запускается?

Comment: получается что при нажатии на первый item что в первом ListView что во втором ListView  переходит на одну и ту же активити)  как сделать что бы при нажати на первый item  в первой ListView  переходило на одну активити а при нажатии на первый item  во втором ListView  на другую активити

Comment: Простого варианта сходу не придумать. Что вам мешает повесить разные слушатели на разные списки?

Comment: вот тут можно немножко по подробней) как повесить разные слушатели на разные списки которые находятся рядом??

Comment: Смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего - повесить разные слушатели клика на разные списки. Например с помощью анонимных классов:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = "
            + id);
      }
    });
listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = "
            + id);
      }
    });
```

Далее, если вы хотите, чтобы при нажатии на пункты второго списка отсчёт был не с нуля - то просто добавьте к `position` кол-во элементов первого списка:

```
int positionInSecondList=position+listView.getAdapter().getCount();
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать как ЮрийСПБ, лично я бы так и сделал, но другой выход, это сделать так, как и вы, но проверять значение **parent** в **switch** и сравнивать с каждым списком и далее реализовывать вашу логику действий